# How to open a URL in a browser at same time send a POST request to that URL on Java 7 FX Application?

Tags: java, http, web, post

Currently there is a desktop application in java that when pressing a button opens a browser with a URL (), the parameters go in the URL so when opening the browser they are read and does what it does (show example: show a beautiful web and print the name and age and year of birth). http: // localhost: 8090 / testvisor? name = john & age = 23Now, the requirement is that the parameters are not visible in the url, that is, that the request is made by POST and not by GET. I managed to open the browser with that URL, but not send the POST request with the name and age. I also managed to send the POST request but I was unable to open the browser with those "obtained" data after the request was sent. That is, the browser opens but no data is detected as in the case of sending the data by url.Note: the method in charge of receiving by POST is fine, since I can send the request and it arrives without problems.Code with which I send the POST request (works):

```
`URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8090/pruebavisor");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("nombre", "juan");
    params.put("edad", "23");
    int tamano = params.size();

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {

        postData.append("\"").append(param.getKey()).append("\":");
        postData.append("\"").append(String.valueOf(param.getValue())).append("\",");

        if (tamano == (tamano - tamano) + 1) {
            postData = new StringBuilder("{" + postData.substring(0, (postData.length() - 1)) + "}");
        }
        tamano--;
    }

    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    for (int c = in.read();c != -1; c = in.read()) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
    }`
```